# Direction of recoil in $B$-decay

Tags: momentum, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, collision, radioactivity

What is the direction of recoil of product nucleus in $B$-decay? I believed it to be by intuition, opposite to the direction of emission $B$-particle but when I wrote that in my exam, it turned out to be wrong. Could you tell which direction and why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a three final particle decay, daughter positive ion, $\beta$ particle and antineutrino with the three momenta adding up to zero.

$m_{\bar \nu}\vec v_{\bar \nu}+ m_+\vec v_+ + m_{\beta_-}\vec v_{\beta_-} = \vec 0$

Comment: I very much understood the equation Sir...but how could we conclude that beta particle and positive ion goes in the same direction or atleast in not the opposite direction?

Comment: @Elizabeth The angle between the electron and the antineutrino is random. For the electron & daughter nucleus to go in opposite directions the antineutrino has to go in that line too, which is very unlikely.